# What are the origins and license of freetype6.dll?

Tags: windows, dll, licensing

Regarding freetype6.dll:

1. Which product does it belong to?
2. What license does it fall under?

In my research, it appears to belong to the Windows OS, and probably ships with all licensed copies of many Windows OS packages and maybe IBM OS packages as well. If I'm correct, can we get more specific?

freetype2 I believe is a completely different, open-source, project. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What is your programming question?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded Freetype 2.4.2 from the [GTK+ project](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php) and it included the file "freetype6.dll". I think took a look at the source files for "freetype6.dll" and the header info said the license was the FreeType project license, but didn't provide a link to it. A quick look on www.freetype.org shows two different [FreeType licenses](http://freetype.org/license.html).

Some of the copyright holders mentioned in the source code are also mentioned on the FreeType project website and Wikipedia page.

I don't know why the DLL is called freetype6.dll and not something like freetype2.dll, but as far as I can see it is from the same project.